# Google Docs Api Python Prevent collections resources to be seen in Home

Tags: python, resources, google-docs-api

I'm trying with the google docs api (python) to create collections and subcollections and to upload files in a created subcollection.

First question:
Everything is ok with the below code, the hierarchy is ok (subfolder1 under the folder1, uploaded file under the subfolder1), **but the only issue is that the subfolder & the file are also seen in the Home for the end user**.
I would like to see only the higher level collection in the Home.

**Is there a way to prevent the resources (sub-collections & files) to be displayed in the Home ?**

Note: I have tried the following alternatives but still get the same result:
1) parameter 'collection=' of create_resource has same result
2) clientlogin or twoleggedoauth have same result

Second question:
**Is it possible to set the description field ?**

```
import gdata.data
import gdata.docs.client
import gdata.acl.data
import gdata.docs.data

GAPPS_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY = "xxxx"
GAPPS_OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET = "xxxxx"
GAPPS_ADMIN_ACCOUNT = "x"

GAPPS_CLIENT_LOGIN_LOGIN='xxxxx'
GAPPS_CLIENT_LOGIN_PWD='xxxxx'
GAPPS_CLIENT_LOGIN_APP='xxxxxx'

filepath = 'C:\\Users\\xxxxx\\Pictures\\'
filename = 'xxxxxx.png'

path = filepath + filename

client = gdata.docs.client.DocsClient()
client.ssl = True
#client.ClientLogin(GAPPS_CLIENT_LOGIN_LOGIN, GAPPS_CLIENT_LOGIN_PWD, GAPPS_CLIENT_LOGIN_APP)
client.auth_token = gdata.gauth.TwoLeggedOAuthHmacToken(GAPPS_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, GAPPS_OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, GAPPS_ADMIN_ACCOUNT)

# create a folder

collection1 = gdata.docs.data.Resource('folder', title = 'Script Folder')
collection1 = client.create_resource(collection1)

# create a sub-folder in collection1

subcollection1 = gdata.docs.data.Resource('folder', title = 'Script Sub Folder')
subcollection1 = client.create_resource(subcollection1)

res = client.move_resource(subcollection1, collection = collection1, keep_in_collections = False)

# Upload the resource in subcollection1

doc = gdata.docs.data.Resource(type = 'file', title = filename)
media = gdata.data.MediaSource()
media.SetFileHandle(path, 'application/octet-stream')
create_uri = gdata.docs.client.RESOURCE_UPLOAD_URI + '?convert=false'
doc = client.CreateResource(doc, create_uri = create_uri, media = media)
print 'Created, and uploaded:', doc.title.text, doc.resource_id.text

client.move_resource(doc, collection = subcollection1, keep_in_collections = False)
```

Comment: In brief, what I need to find is : how to do the ui feature "don't show in home" through the python classes

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

```
subcollection1 = gdata.docs.data.Resource('folder', title = 'Script Sub Folder')
subcollection1.AddCategory(gdata.docs.data.LABELS_NS, gdata.docs.data.LABELS_NS + "#" +gdata.docs.data.HIDDEN_LABEL, gdata.docs.data.HIDDEN_LABEL)
subcollection1 = client.create_resource(subcollection1)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another much simpler approach.

```
subcollection1 = client.create_resource(subcollection1,collection=collection1)
```

The script sub folder never appears on your root folder by this approach.